# How to split array in json using json_query?

Tags: t-sql

I've got a column in a table that's a json. It contains only values without keys like

[image]

Now I'm trying to split the data from the json and create new table using every index of each array as new entry like

[image]

I've already tried

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(abc) as 'Type', Id as 'ValueId' from Table FOR JSON AUTO
```

Is there any way to handle splitting given that some arrays might be empty and look like

```
[]
```

?

Comment: `[Id] 1 [Values] '[10,12,16]'` is not json. Please edit your question to include a proper json formatted value. It would also improve your chances of getting a good answer if you could throw in the DDL of the table, some sample data as DML and desired results as well.

Comment: Added images as I apparently can't "write" what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly simply approach would be to use `outer apply` with `openjson`.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Id int,
    Value nvarchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, '[10]'),
(2, '[20, 200]'),
(3, '[]'),
(4, '')
```

The query:

```
SELECT Id, JsonValues.Value
FROM @T As t
OUTER APPLY
OPENJSON( Value ) As JsonValues
WHERE ISJSON(t.Value) = 1
```

Results:

```
Id  Value
1   10
2   20
2   200
3   NULL
```

Note the `ISJSON` condition in the `where` clause will prevent exceptions in case the `Value` column contains anything other than a valid json (an empty array `[]` is still considered valid for this purpose).

If you don't want to return a row where the json array is empty, use `cross apply` instead of `outer apply`.

Comment: @Shnugo thanks, though I think the better part of this answer is the introduction of proper sample data, including edge cases, which is what forced me to add the `isjson` condition in the first place :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will remember to create sample tables in future!

Comment: @Easy I'm [Glad to help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327), and even more glad to read your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your own code calling for `FOR JSON AUTO` tries to create JSON out of tabular data. But what you really needs seems to be the opposite direction: You want to transform JSON to a result set, a *derived table*. This is done by [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Your JSON seems to be a very minimalistic array.

You can try something along this.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) =N'[1,2,3]';

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json);
```

The result returns the *zero-based* ordinal position in `key`, the actual value in `value` and a (very limited) *type-enum*.

Hint: If you want to use this against a table's column you must use `APPLY`, something along

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(t.TheJsonColumn);
```